# vb.net looping through controls and my.settings variables

Tags: vb.net

i have 20 text boxes and 20 my.settings variables

textboxes and my.settings variables have the same names
textbox name: mid0 and it has the value of my.settings.mid0

the text boxes are created in runtime 
and i have a save button and  that will save the values of the text boxes in my.settings variables

here is the code

```
Dim Ctl As Control
    Dim MyTextbox As TextBox
    For i As Integer = 0 To 20
        Ctl = tabc.TabPages(6).Controls.Item("mid" & i.ToString)
        If Ctl IsNot Nothing Then
            MyTextbox = CType(Ctl, TextBox)
            My.Settings.("mid" & i.ToString) = MyTextbox.Text 'this line is the problem
        End If
    Next
```

so how do i loop through the my.settings variables?
which goes form mid0 to mid20

i tried

```
CallByName(My.Settings, "mid" & i.ToString, CallType.Set) = MyTextbox.Text
```

but i get an error "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment."

Comment: This is a built-in feature that requires no code.  Select the textbox and click ApplicationSettings in the Property window.

Comment: but text boxes are added at runtime so i can't select the text box :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the My.Settings line to

```
My.Settings("mid" & i.ToString) = MyTextbox.Text
```

which really amounts to removing the period :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't write CallByName(...)=smtg. Because CallByName is a function, not property.
But the 4th parameter of CallByName let's you do all what you want.
Here's the code you need which will work without changing all your code:

```
CallByName(My.Settings, "mid" & i.ToString, CallType.Set, MyTextbox.Text)
```

I think this will help you very much. Good Luck !